# Limit of a product of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, products

> **Let $a > 0$ and $\{y_n\}_{n\geq0}$ be a sequence such that $y_0 > 0$, $y_n > a \ \forall \ n > 1$ and**
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {y_n} \to \infty$$
>
> **Prove That**
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac a {y_k}\right) = 0 $$

I tried to expand the product using Vieta's formula, but I'm getting the product to be infinite.

> **Edit :** I'm adding the source of the problem. I found it at the end of Theorem 1 on page 7 of [this PDF](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8nse92MLTAhXBQY8KHYNHDv8QFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmat.uab.cat%2Fpubmat%2Ffitxers%2Fdownload%2FFileType%3Apdf%2FFolderName%3Av50(1)%2FFileName%3A50106_01.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEi5StNyNl297sd6ISdXSK5dEZJFw).
>
> Here is a screenshot
>
> [image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need the condition $0<a/s_k \le 1$.

Comment: Does "where $a>0$ is constant" mean "for every constant $a>0$" or "for some constant $a>0$"? (The word "where" used in this way, should explain the notation; it shouldn't be used as a quantifier.) $\qquad$

Comment: Observe that the statement to be proved, as it is stated, is not true. By example let $s_k:=k^{-2}$, then obviously $\sum 1/s_k=\sum k^2=\infty$ and if $a^{-1/2}\notin \Bbb N$ then $\prod(1-a/s_k)=\prod(1-ak^2)$ diverges to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Using the userabc modifications on the assumptions about $a$ and $s_k$, you can use $\log(1+x) \leq x$ for all $x >-1$, which is a handy inequality.

Comment: We need an assumption that $\dfrac{1}{y_n} \to 0$ or something similar. Do we have that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Added some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the strict convexity of the exponential function, we have

$$1 - x \leqslant e^{-x}\tag{1}$$

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and the inequality is strict for all $x \neq 0$. The assumptions yield $0 < 1 - \frac{a}{y_k} \leqslant 1$ for $k > 1$ (probably a typo and it should have been $\geqslant 1$, but that doesn't matter). Using $(1)$, we find

$$0 < \prod_{k = 2}^m \biggl(1 - \frac{a}{y_k}\biggr) \leqslant \exp \Biggl(-a \sum_{k = 2}^m \frac{1}{y_k}\Biggr)\tag{2}$$

for all $m \geqslant 2$. The assumption $\sum \frac{1}{y_k} = +\infty$ implies that the right hand side of $(2)$ tends to $0$ as $m \to \infty$, hence by squeezing we deduce

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \prod_{k = 2}^m \biggl(1 - \frac{a}{y_k}\biggr) = 0.$$

Multiplying with the constant $1 - \frac{a}{y_1}$ yields

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \prod_{k = 1}^m \biggl(1 - \frac{a}{y_k}\biggr) = 0.$$